# Run ecryptfs from live USB (Solved)

Tags: data-recovery, ecryptfs

I am trying to recover an encrypted home folder from a broken system. I found several posts on this, referring to running ecryptfs-recover-private from a live session.  Trying this using a 18.04 on a USB flash drive but ecryptfs is not installed. Output from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ecryptfs-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ecryptfs-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ecryptfs-utils' has no installation candidate
```

As an alternate is it possible to copy the entire encryped folder over to another hard drive before fresh install of 18.04 and then recover it?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then add universe on the end of each repository line (except for the `deb cdrom` line).

You can then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils` to install the package.